# Apache Site Configuration Share Settings

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, virtualization, hosts

For our WordPress development server, each developer has a subdomain to work on the site which point to the same server and database, but different folder locations. This allows us to see database changes immediately but we all code independently at the file level.

To do this, I have a separate apache site configuration for each subdomain. Example:
Developer A: a.site.com
Developer B: b.site.com

It works well, but I maintain two separate site configuration files (a and b) in /etc/apache2/sites-available that are 90% the same. Is there way to have the configuration files (a and b) "include" a common configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including other files into Apache config is very simple:

```
# some comment here so you know what it does
Include "/path/to/your/config.file"
```

Comment: Thanks.

After I set up the directory directive, I do an include of other server files.

<Directory /_______>
        Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/rewrite-rules
        Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/html5-boilerplate
</Directory>

Now I can modify the rewrite rules for all the sites in one place.